# jquery event argument within div css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zooming

My target goal is to enlarge a picture within a div and shrink a background-picture of a div.

I have a first javascript that alters the IMG element within the .pixbox DIV. This works.

I have a second javascript that alters the background-image from .pixbox DIV.

Question: How do i select the control the element through .on() event argument
I tried with .css('background-image') but that doesnt seem to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/q9jHu/347/

**CSS**

```
.pixbox {
    background:url()
```

**javascript**

```
$('.pixbox').css('background-image').on({
            mouseover: function(){

                var $scale = 0.7;
                if ($(this).data('w')) {
                    var $w = $(this).data('w');
                    var $h = $(this).data('h');
                } else {
                    var $w = $(this).width();
                    var $h = $(this).height();
                    $(this).data('w', $w).data('h', $h);
            }
          <rest of code>
```

**html**

```
<div class="pixbox">
    <img class="zoom" src="">
</div>
```

Comment: In your fiddle you're using a `mouseout` event which doesn't exist. You should be using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself! but the code is still a bit buggy
http://jsfiddle.net/q9jHu/360/

```
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons/glossy-black-icons-business/080837-glossy-black-icon-business-magnifying-glass-ps.png) no-repeat center center;
    transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 2s ease-in-out;
}
div:hover {background-size: 60% 60%;}
```